# How to import specified cells in csv to oracle table with sql loader

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle11g, sql-loader

Given csv file 'example.csv'

I would like to load 
cell C7 into column X 
cell C8 into column Y 
cell D7 into column Z

of oracle table 'exampletable'

And so on. The csv file does not have orderly rows and columns, so I cannot just load the csv file into a new table cleanly. So what I am asking is how to map *cells* to table columns loading this file into Oracle (XE). Can anyone point me to a tutorial?

I realize this is pretty elementary, please let me know if I have under-specified anything in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's an elementary task. You may follow this tutorial (for example): http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ To choose cells you may try to CASE WHEN in your mapping + you may add a column in your csv to designate row number and use it as well

Comment: You're right there, it turned out to be not an elementary task at all. Thanks for the link; I was hoping Oracle would offer some utility that I couldn't do in SQL, but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

SQL*Loader operates on *rows* of input data and shoves them into a table.  You can either append rows to a table, or truncate the table and insert.  There is no updating.  You want to load data from a column in the input file into different table columns, which it does not do.

That said, one IS able use the 'when' clause of the control file to load an entire **ROW**  differently based on the value being tested.  So, for example, one could have parent and child records in one csv data file as long as there is an input data column that differentiates between the two that you could key off of.  Perhaps you could get tricky and use this to achieve your desired result if the data you want to load has a column you can key off of so that row will load differently.

For example here is a sample control file that loads from one csv file into 2 tables, depending on the first field.  If 'P' data is loaded into the parent table, if 'C' data is loaded into the child table.  If you have a csv data column with a value you can test to see which row format to use, I would expect you could load into the same table differently, just by specifying a different layout.  So, your **ROW** with C7 going to table.column X would need to load differently from your **ROW** where C8 goes into table.column Y.  You have to specify the entire row though.  I would be interested to see the result if you try it.

```
OPTIONS (DIRECT=TRUE)
UNRECOVERABLE
LOAD DATA
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE LOAD_TEST_PARENT_ROWS
WHEN (01) = 'P'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
 rec_skip filler POSITION(1)
,CLM_CLAIM_ID    CHAR NULLIF(CLM_CLAIM_ID=BLANKS)
,FILE_PURPOSE_CD CHAR NULLIF(FILE_PURPOSE_CD=BLANKS)
,FILE_REF_ID     CHAR NULLIF(FILE_REF_ID=BLANKS)
)
INTO TABLE LOAD_TEST_CHILD_ROWS
WHEN (01) = 'C'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
 rec_skip filler POSITION(1)
,SL_CLAIM    CHAR NULLIF(SL_CLAIM=BLANKS)
,SL_LINE_NBR CHAR NULLIF(SL_LINE_NBR=BLANKS)
,SL_D_PROC   CHAR NULLIF(SL_D_PROC=BLANKS)
)
```

Let us know what happens when you load to the same table, this will be a good one for the bag of tricks.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggested solution.

I ended up having to do this in Excel, in a very laborious process. There were 112 such cells from each of 485 spreadsheets, so coding something proved too much. 

It sure would be great if there was some kind of GUI utility that would allow a user to select cells from an open workbook and map them to columns in SQL, Oracle and hit a button that basically says "let's call that a 'row' and bring it on in."

Whoever can develop such an app will make some money, but it ain't gonna be me.